# Redis on EC2 (Heroku) : RedisToGo v/s MyRedis v/s OpenRedis v/s RedisCloud v/s Others

Tags: amazon-ec2, heroku, redis

Are there opinions and experiences to help decide between RedisToGo v/s MyRedis v/s OpenRedis v/s RedisCloud v/s Any Other Hosted Redis offerings?

The goal is to have minimal latency and maximal performance for a Heroku application (which is in EC2 in US-EAST / Virginia). I put the names of above 4, as they are in the Addons-List at Heroku.